# Barplot with threshold

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have a huge data frame consisting of binary values (extract):

```
id,topic,w_hello,w_apple,w_tomato
1,politics,1,1,0
2,sport,0,1,0
3,politics,1,0,1
```

With:

```
barplot(col_prefix_matrix)
```

I plot the number of their occurrences:

[image]

As there are many columns, the plot looks very confusing.

Would it be possible to plot only those columns with a specific threshold, say 5, to make it look more clear?

Comment: Based on the example showed, what do you expect.  THe 2nd and 3rd column have 2 1's and the last with 1 1s.

Comment: You can do `df1[c(TRUE, TRUE, colSums(df1[-(1:2)])>5)]`

Comment: @akrun: This data frame is just an extract. My real df has over 1.000 columns.

Comment: Based on the description, the code above should subset only columns with sum > 5 along with the Id and the next column.

Comment: What does `[-(1:2)]` mean?

Comment: It means we are excluding the 1st two column as these are not of interest ?